# How i can get guides that are actual on the specified date

Tags: python, mysql, django-orm

I have in the database:

Guide1 = (name="diagnoses", version="1.0", start_date="2022-10-01")

Guide2 = (name="diagnoses", version="2.0", start_date="2022-10-05")

Guide3 = (name="professions", version="1.0", start_date="2022-10-01")

Guide4 = (name="professions", version="2.0", start_date="2022-10-05")

If i say date="2022-10-06", i want to see just Guide2 and Guide4

models.py:

```
class Guide(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255, unique=False,
                            blank=True, null=True)
    short_name = models.CharField('Short Name', max_length=63,
                                  unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField('Description', unique=False,
                                   blank=True, null=True)
    version = models.CharField('Version', max_length=63)
    start_date = models.DateField(
        'Date of start guide this version')

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['version', 'start_date'])
        ]
        unique_together = ('name', 'version')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.short_name} version-{self.version}'
```

views.py now:

```
... 
queryset = Guide.objects.filter(start_date__lte=date)
...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this decision:

```
        elems_pk = []
        names_unique = Guide.objects.values_list('name').distinct()
        for name in names_unique:
            elem = Guide.objects.filter(name=name[0],start_date__lte=date).latest('start_date')
            elems_pk.append(elem.pk)
        queryset = Guide.objects.filter(pk__in=elems_pk)
```